# Active noise control

Tags: noise, control, active-noise-control

In most papers I search for benefits of active noise control, most of them contain one single sentence without explanation that ANC increased material durability and fatigue life. But why?

Comment: Context please?

Comment: Additional benefits of ANC include: 
-increased material durability and fatigue life 
-lower operating costs due to reduced facility down-time for installation and maintenance 
-reduced operator fatigue and improved ergonomics 
-the compact size and modularity of active systems can provide additional flexibility in product design, even to the point of a complete product redesign

Comment: Active Noise Control FAQ, General Discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metal fatigue can be due to vibration. So I guess if you can reduce the vibration using ANC, the metal fatigue will be lessened, and thereby the durability will increase.

Comment: EMV is correct, even micro vibrations can cause fatigue in materials and active noise cancellation can help prolong the life of materials that vibrate.